# How to block the OCDNet pipeline and get the result only on OCRNet? (NVIDIA-Optical-Character-Detection-and-Recognition-Solution/OCDR)

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, nvidia

I am running the NVIDIA-Optical-Character-Detection-and-Recognition-Solution locally on my Jetson. I want to block the pipeline of OCDNet and only infer with OCRNet. I commented out all the code related to OCDNet. By the result is coming out as empty inference.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. The OCDNet output it's detection as polygon points. Then the output of OCDNet is inserted into OCRNet as input. I created a polygon which represents the whole image and inserted it into OCRNet and blocked the OCDNet polygons.